# Report Server WMI Provider Error: Invalid namespace when connecting to Report Server Instance on Reporting Services Config Manager

Tags: sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019, ssrs, errors, ssrs-2016

I have two SQL Server 2016 instances (Instance A and Instance B) on the same server. Both instances have SSRS. At one point I upgraded Instance A to SQL Server 2019 but then due to the changes made to SSRS in 2019 I decided to bring Instance A back to 2016. I can connect to Instance A just fine on SQL Server 2016 Reporting Services Configuration Manager but now every time I try to connect to Instance B I receive this error:

Report Server WMI Provider error:
Invalid namespace.

I've done some research and can't find a situation exactly like this. Does anyone know of a fix for this or have an idea of where I could find some more information on the problem? Before I try uninstalling and reinstalling SSRS on Instance B I wanted to see if I could find a fix that didn't require uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: I have the same error. The "Report Server Web Service URL" is correct. I can see that it says "You can integrate this SharePoint environment with an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services or SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services to enable full reporting functionality", so now I am thinking the new Reporting Services is not compatible with this version as it is "SQL Server 2019 Reporting Services"